# $3$D oriented bounding box optimization

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

Given: a set $S$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Find: [the smallest oriented bounding box that contains all the points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms). Note, the bounding box is "oriented" and thus need not be axis-aligned.

Can this be formulated as an optimization problem? Preferably a *convex* optimization problem!

The optimal box should be smallest by either volume or perimeter (whichever is easier, but ideally, both solutions will be presented).

I hope the optimization problem is simpler to code than [Joseph O'Rourke's Minimum Enclosing Box Algorithm (pdf)](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/Papers/MinVolBox.pdf) and can be solved using a standard optimization package.

For example, the smallest enclosing *hypersphere* containing a set of points $S$ can be defined by a center $c$ and radius $r$. It is the solution to the problem:

$$\textrm{minimize}_{c,r} \; r^2 \;\;$$
$$ \textrm{subject to: } \; \left| \left| c - s \right| \right|^2 \leq r^2 \; \forall s \in S$$

I'm asking for a similar formulation for an oriented bounding box instead of a hypersphere, if possible.

Comment: Are you asking to solve the same problem as in my paper you cite, but just by a different method?  Hopefully using off-the-shelf optimization code?  Or are you asking to solve a different problem?

Comment: I am asking to solve the exact same problem you address in your paper. I am asking how to formulate the problem in standard optimization form: "minimize f(x) subject to g(x) <= 0", so that I can solve it using off-the-shelf optimization code. I hope this formulation is simpler to code than the rotating calipers algorithm in the paper.

Comment: @dsg: Thanks, I now understand.  It's a good question! But I have no answer off the top of my head.

Comment: The most straightforward (naïve?) way of doing this would be to optimize over all possible oriented boxes as a 9-dimensional space, the way your example optimizes over the 4-dimensional space of all possible spheres. Are you looking for something cleverer than this?

Comment: Sure, that would be a nice start. I think the hypersphere problem as I've formulated it is a second-order cone program, and there are standard tools that can solve it (but I'm pretty sure there are better methods). Can your naive formulation be solved via some standard tools?

Comment: @dsg: If you include "@name" in your comment, the other user gets notified of it. To address your comment, I don't know if my naive formulation can be solved efficiently using standard tools, but it seems unlikely. The difficulty as I see it is that unlike the spherical case, you need three degrees of freedom to describe the orientations of the box, which do not form a vector space at all. (The space of rotations can be parametrised as the unit 4-sphere in the quaternions, but that isn't a nice convex constraint either.)

Comment: @dsg: aren't you basically looking for a set of orthogonal (affine) hyperplanes that enclose your set of points? That is how polyhedral norms are defined. This is just a suggestion but you may be able to formulate your problem as: look for $2n$ vectors $a_1$ through $a_{2n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $2n$ scalars $b_1$ through $b_{2n}$ such that $a_i^T x - b_i \geq 0$ and $a_{2i}^T x - b_{2i} \leq 0$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and all $x \in S$. You may impose $\|a_i\| = 1$ and you need $a_i$ parallel to $a_{2i}$ (you could choose them equal) and $a_i \perp a_j$ ($j \not \in \{i,2i\}$).

Answer (score 2):

An easy formulation that can be solved using Sequential Quadratic Programming, follows

Defining

$$
\cases{
p = (x,y,z)\\
p_i = (x_i,y_i,y_i), \ \ \ i = 1,\cdots,m\\
\vec n_i = (\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i),\ (c_i,d_i),\ \ \ i = 1,2,3\\
\|\vec n_i\| = 1\\
\vec n_i\cdot \vec n_j = 0,\ \ \ i\ne j\\
}
$$

so

$$
\min_{\phi}f,\ \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ \ R
$$

the objective function $f = \left(\prod_{i=1}^3(c_i-d_i)\right)^2$ and the restrictions

$$
\cases{
r_{j,k}=p_k\cdot \vec n_i+c_i > 0\\
s_{j,k}=p_k\cdot \vec n_i+d_i < 0\\
k = 1,\cdots,m, \ \ \ j=1,2,3
}
$$

with $\phi = \cup_i(\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i,c_i,d_i)$ and $R=\cases{\cup_{i,j}(r_{i,j},s_{i,j})\cup_i(\|\vec n_i\|=1)\cup_{i,j}(\vec n_i\cdot \vec n_j = 0)}$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which implements this procedure

```
m = 30;
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 3}];
p = {x, y, z};
Pl[p_, n_, del_] := p.n + del
n1 = {alpha1, beta1, gamma1};
n2 = {alpha2, beta2, gamma2};
n3 = {alpha3, beta3, gamma3};
restr1 = n1.n1 - 1 == 0;
restr2 = n2.n2 - 1 == 0;
restr3 = n3.n3 - 1 == 0;
restr4 = n1.n2 == 0;
restr5 = n1.n3 == 0;
restr6 = n2.n3 == 0;
restra = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n1, c1] > 0, {k, 1, m}];
restrb = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n1, c2] < 0, {k, 1, m}];
restrc = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n2, c3] > 0, {k, 1, m}];
restrd = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n2, c4] < 0, {k, 1, m}];
restre = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n3, c5] > 0, {k, 1, m}];
restrf = Table[Pl[data[[k]], n3, c6] < 0, {k, 1, m}];
restr = Join[Join[Join[Join[Join[restra, restrb], restrc],restrd], restre], restrf];
restrs = Join[restr, {restr1, restr2, restr3, restr4, restr5, restr6}];
obj = ((c1 - c2) (c3 - c4) (c5 - c6))^2;
vars = Join[Join[Join[n1, n2], n3], {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6}];
sol = NMinimize[{obj, restrs}, vars]

points = Table[Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data[[k]]]}], {k, 1, m}];
normals = {n1, n1, n2, n2, n3, n3} /. sol[[2]];
consts = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6} /. sol[[2]];
planes = Table[ContourPlot3D[Pl[p, normals[[k]], consts[[k]]] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> False, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.2], Specularity[White, 30]]], {k, 1, 6}];
Show[points, planes, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]